# Custom image placement on map

Tags: css, google-maps, overlay, openlayers, leaflet

i've got 40 images. I want to place them on a grid (or at specific location on a map). The fact that imageA is in point [0,0] depends on some info from the user actually logged in.
Which means, for user1, he will see in [0,0] the imageA, and for user2 he could see in [0,0] imageC.

That could be done with some css, but the problem is, all those images are supposed to be part of a map. So users can zoomin/out/pan, managing click on specific area etc...

My first though would be using leaflet with transparent tiles. My 40 images could be 40 imageoverlays placed on the map. But that would be pretty rough to adjust sizing, and it would require to have 40*4 images (if i want 4 levels of zoom). Something like generating my imageA in 1000*1000, 500*500, 250*250, 125*125 and hope thats actually the good sizing.

Do you have any idea (not specificaly on leaflet) how could i achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your images to scale, then it sounds like your grid is based off the viewport? In which case, using html/css to handle things sounds like the best option.

Otherwise, you can consider using [InfoWindows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows). You can have an image within the InfoWindow. The location on the map will stay the same and the size of the window should not scale with the zoom either.

Comment: i want it to scale, but i dont want to use a 500Ko image when they are zoomed out and this image is actually showing on 50*50.
need it to be smooth like tiles are.
probably dont have a lot of options, thx for the help